# Порядок конструирования аргументов функции

Tags: c++

Встретил статью «[Пять подводных камней при использовании shared_ptr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191018/)»,
в которой утверждается, что:

> в строке кода:
>
> ```
> foo( shared_ptr<Widget>(new Widget), bar() );
> ```
>
> порядок конструирования не определен.
>   Все зависит от конкретного компилятора
>   и флагов компиляции. Например, это
>   может произойти так:
>
> 1. new Widget
> 2. вызов функции bar
> 3. конструирование shared_ptr
> 4. вызов функции foo

Почему так? Я считал, что в списке параметров функции точки следования определены запятыми и аргументы (границы между которыми очерчивают запятые) действительно могут быть обработаны в любом порядке, НО каждый отдельный аргумент, если уж начал обрабатываться программой, то обрабатывается до конца. А т.к. `shared_ptr<Widget>(new Widget)` - это отдельный аргумент, то он обработается целиком (т.е. в приведённом списке пункты 1 и 3 всегда будут идти подряд).

Разве не так? Ткните, пожалуйста, меня носом в "что бы прочесть", чтобы уяснить свою ошибку.
Спасибо.

**Обновление**

@KoVadim, в статье рассматривается случай, когда выполнение `bar()` бросает исключение. Тогда (исходя из предложенного порядка обработки аргументов) получается, что объект `Widget` сконструирован, но `shared_ptr` ещё нет (следовательно и не завладел объектом `Widget`). Отсюда утечка памяти.

**Обновление 2**

@KoVadim, да, действительно, Вы правы. Дело именно в этом. Прочёл дальше комментарии к статье - там кто-то уже задал подобный вопрос. В ответ ему посоветовали ссылку http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm Тут разбирается подобный случай. А причина неопределённости, как Вы уже заметили, в том, что запятая, отделяющая параметры функции друг от друга - это разделитель (comma separator), а не оператор запятая (comma operator). А точкой следования из них является только оператор.
Спасибо за пинок в правильном направлении.

Comment: @Sasha K, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

В статье на хабре написано все верно.

Вот выдержка из [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order):

> “Sequenced-before” is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relationship between evaluations within the same thread (it may extend across threads if atomic types and memory barriers are involved).
>
> If a sequence point is present between the subexpressions E1 and E2, then both value computation and side effects of E1 are sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2
>
> If evaluation A is sequenced before evaluation B, then evaluation of A will be complete before evaluation of B begins. (since C11)
>
> If A is not sequenced before B and B is sequenced before A, then evaluation of B will be complete before evaluation of A begins. (since C11)
>
> If A is not sequenced before B and B is not sequenced before A, then two possibilities exist: (since C11)
>
> - evaluations of A and B are unsequenced: they may be performed in any order and may overlap (within a single thread of execution, the compiler may interleave the CPU instructions that comprise A and B)
> - evaluations of A and B are indeterminably-sequenced: they may be performed in any order but may not overlap: either A will be complete before B, or B will be complete before A. The order may be the opposite the next time the same expression is evaluated.

Как видите, в случае, если порядок А и Б не определен, возможны два варианта: с оверлапом и без него.

Собственно, написанная Вами выше последовательность, когда `bar()` вызывается между `new` и вызовом конструктора, является первым случаем, вполне возможным согласно стандарту.

Место, о котором я говорю:

> - evaluations of A and B are unsequenced: they may be performed in any order and may overlap (within a single thread of execution, the compiler may interleave the CPU instructions that comprise A and B)

Comment: Да, создатели стандарта подстраховались и развязали руки будущим "реализаторам"

(все равно ведь в конце-концов сделают так, как им покажется правильней, а предсказать сейчас новые архитектуры ...).

Comment: @avp, по-моему, это очень неверное развязывание) Правила нужны, чтобы облегчать жизнь пользователю (программисту), а не разработчику (реализатору компилятора). Соответственно, они должны быть просты и лаконичны, интуитивно понятны, насколько это возможно. Имхо тут что-то вроде "а давайте наш дробовик еще и себе в ногу стрелять будет, вдруг производителю дробовика так будет легче его сделать")

Comment: А почему никто не плюсует?

Comment: @smallFish, Вы пишете (о правилах):

     ... они должны быть просты и лаконичны, интуитивно понятны, насколько это возможно.

Золотые слова.

Осталось понять, насколько они в принципе применимы к монстру под названием С++.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые, разделяющие аргументы функции, и оператор запятая - это разные вещи.

По поводу порядка вычисления. А какая разница? Проблемы будут только в том случае, если конструктор shared_ptr зависит от bar() (глобальными переменными), но это уже страх и ужас.

Comment: @KoVadim: Разница может быть, если вычисление `bar()` может выбросить exception: `Widget`, не записанный в `shared_ptr`, будет потерян.